# How can I get the value from span class in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

[image: the html code]

In the code above, how would I get the span class value (238.67) to show up? What would I exactly use?

Answer (score 2):

enter code hereI assume you have only one span tag.

This xpath will locate the element.  `//span[contains(@class,'Trsdu')]`

Below code will return you the **238.67** value

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'Trsdu')]").text
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing context here and I am not super sure what do you mean by to *show up* but to get that value I would use the data-reactid as selector and just get the innerhtml text on that element.

Answer (score 0):

If the span's class value does not include multiple keywords then we can easily extract the element's text using locator "//span[@class ='Trsdu']" with **'.text' property.**

Please refer below code:

```
print("Text Returned", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='Trsdu']").text)
```

However, the span element provided in the screenshot -> has multiple keywords in its class value. ***So for this scenario***,   software testing services use '.contains' method to locate the element and the same *.text property* can be used to extract the element's text

Please refer below code:

```
print("Text extracted using contains", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'Trsdu')]").text)
```

For the '.contains' approach, always try to use a unique keyword from the provided class value to avoid returning multiple elements.